# Appflow liveupdate don't work on my project

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-appflow

Live update are not working on my side. 
The core is developed with reactjs, built with webpack
What i did :

- Add the Appflow SDK, the strings.xml is now modified
- commit & push
- Build the native .apk from Appflow GUI
- Install the .apk on my device
- Change one string in the code
- Commit
- Build a Web Deploy and assign it to the Production Channel
- As the update method is "auto" i close the app, relaunch it, but the modified string is not updated

Any suggestion on what i could missed ?

Thanks

strings.xml

```
<resources>
  <string name="ionic_app_id">XXXXXXXXX</string>
  <string name="ionic_channel_name">Production</string>
  <string name="ionic_update_method">auto</string>
</resources>
```

ionic info

```
[11:35:24]: $ ionic info
[11:35:25]: ▸ Ionic:
[11:35:25]: ▸ Ionic CLI       : 6.2.2 (/usr/local/nvm/versions/node/v10.19.0/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
[11:35:25]: ▸ Ionic Framework : @ionic/react 5.0.5
[11:35:25]: ▸ Capacitor:
[11:35:25]: ▸ Capacitor CLI   : 1.5.1
[11:35:25]: ▸ @capacitor/core : 1.5.1
[11:35:25]: ▸ Utility:
[11:35:25]: ▸ cordova-res : 0.10.0
[11:35:25]: ▸ native-run  : not installed
[11:35:25]: ▸ System:
[11:35:25]: ▸ NodeJS : v10.19.0 (/usr/local/nvm/versions/node/v10.19.0/bin/node)
[11:35:25]: ▸ npm    : 6.13.4
[11:35:25]: ▸ OS     : Linux 4.14
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the case of the destination channel name.  *Production* vs *production*.  I believe the default values are misleading.